# How to call two methods on button's onClick method in Vf Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, custom-button

I am having two functions one is java script function named as Capturing Signature()  and  anther one apex class function named as savePDF(). I am trying to call this two methods on button's onClick method in VF Page. For this so far i have tried this.

```
**This code calling only one method "SavePDF()"**
      <input id="saveSigButton" type="button" name="SigCap" onclick="CaptureSignature();savePDF();" value="Submit"/ >

*This code calling only one method "CaptureSignature()"**

      <input id="saveSigButton" type="button" name="SigCap" onclick="CaptureSignature(),savePDF()" value="Submit"/ >
```

Kindly help to resolve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To call apex class (controller) function named **savePDF()**, use **[apex:commandButton](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)** component with action attribute binding set to **{!savePDF}**, calling the **savePDF()** method of the underlying controller:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!savePDF}" value="Save" id="theButton" />
```

To call JS function named **CaptureSignature()** on click of the button, use **[apex:commandButton](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)** with onclick attribute set to **CaptureSignature();**:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="CaptureSignature();" value="Save" id="theButton" />
```

To call both, the controller method as well as the JS function, use **[apex:commandButton](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)** with both **action** and **onclick** attributes set:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!savePDF}" onclick="CaptureSignature();" value="Save" id="theButton"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can user  to call Apex function in VF page. for example:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="savePDF" action="{!savePDF}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" onclick="savePDF(),CaptureSignature()"/>
```

[for more reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

Java script functions you can invoke normally.

Comment: thanks for reply i tried this function but savepdf only run

Answer (score 1):

You can use apex function with java-script to implement this :

```
<apex:actionFunction name="savePDFApex" action="{!savePDF}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function CaptureSignature() {
/*
do what you want to do.
*/
savePDFApex();
}

</>

<apex:commandButton value="Save" id="theButton" onclick="CaptureSignature()"/>
```

Comment: thanks for reply i tried this function but savepdf only run

Comment: @Lavanya Sanathkumar I have updated the code. I have removed action attribute from commandButton. You can try this now. It should  work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:actionFunction name="savePDF" action="{!savePDF}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" onclick="savePDF()"/>
```

use ActionFunction for calling two methods on single command button click.
onclick event runs the ActionFunction and the second method will be called

Comment: <apex:actionFunction name="savePDF" action="{!savePDF}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" onclick="savePDF()"/>